# impl Stream cannot be unpinned

Tags: rust, rust-futures

I'm trying to get data using [`crates_io_api`](https://docs.rs/crates_io_api/0.7.0/crates_io_api/).
I attempted to get data from a stream, but
I can not get it to work.

[`AsyncClient::all_crates`](https://docs.rs/crates_io_api/0.7.0/crates_io_api/struct.AsyncClient.html#method.all_crates) returns an `impl Stream`. How do I get data from it? It would be helpful if you provide code.

I checked out [the async book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/05_streams/02_iteration_and_concurrency.html) but it didn't work.
Thank you.

Here's my current code.

```
use crates_io_api::{AsyncClient, Error};
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

async fn get_all(query: Option<String>) -> Result<crates_io_api::Crate, Error> {
  // Instantiate the client.
  let client = AsyncClient::new(
    "test (test@test.com)",
    std::time::Duration::from_millis(10000),
  )?;

  let stream = client.all_crates(query);

  // what should I do after?
  // ERROR: `impl Stream cannot be unpinned`
  while let Some(item) = stream.next().await {
      // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Thanks. I tried it but got long errors. I updated the code in the post

Comment: This is likely a mistake on the side of `crates_io_api`. They should be returning an `impl Stream + Unpin`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like a mistake on the side of `crates_io_api`. Getting the `next` element of a `Stream` requires that the `Stream` is `Unpin`:

```rust
pub fn next(&mut self) -> Next<'_, Self> where
    Self: Unpin,
```

Because `Next` stores a reference to `Self`, you must guarantee that `Self` is not moved during the process, or risk pointer invalidation. This is what the `Unpin` marker trait represents. `crates_io_api` does not provide this guarantee (although they could, and should be), so you must make it yourself. To convert a `!Unpin` type to a `Unpin` type, you can pin it to a heap allocation:

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

let stream = client.all_crates(query).boxed();

// boxed simply calls Box::pin
while let Some(elem) = stream.next() { ... }
```

Or you can pin it to the stack with the [`pin_mut!`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/macro.pin_mut.html)/[`pin!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.5.0/tokio/macro.pin.html) macro:

```rust
let stream = client.all_crates(query);
futures::pin_mut!(stream);

while let Some(elem) = stream.next() { ... }
```

Alternatively, you could use a combinator that does not require `Unpin` such as [`for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each):

```rust
stream.for_each(|elem| ...)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I didnt know about Pin, so this is a good time to study

Comment: There's a great blog post explaining the concept of pinning and why it's necessary: https://fasterthanli.me/articles/pin-and-suffering