# Pin<Box<Stream>> returns an empty stream

Tags: rust, stream

I have an object that produces a stream. I would like to use that stream by collecting its items. But, in my settings, I can only use that stream through a trait:

```rust
use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};
use std::pin::Pin;

pub trait GetStream {
    fn get_stream(&self) -> Box<dyn Stream<Item = u32>>;
}
```

The streamer produces a stream that is *NOT* `Unpin`, (in my case, because I use unfold). I know that, in the following example, I could have used another method, such as `repeat_with`, and that produce a `<dyn Box<Stream<...> + Unpin>` and the case is closed... but no, in real life, I need that `unfold`, so my Stream is `!Unpin`:

```rust
pub struct Streamer {
    begin: u32,
    count: usize,
}

impl GetStream for Streamer {
    fn get_stream(&self) -> Box<dyn Stream<Item = u32>> {
        let stream = stream::unfold((self.begin, self.count), |(cur, count)| async move {
            if count == 0 {
                let next_state = (cur + 1, count - 1);
                let yielded = next_state.0;
                Some((yielded, next_state))
            } else {
                None
            }
        });

        Box::new(stream)
    }
}
```

On the user's side, I'd like to use `collect` on the Stream, but that does require the stream to be `Unpin`:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let streamer = Streamer { begin: 4, count: 4 };
    let stream = streamer.get_stream();
    let stream = Pin::new(stream);
    let vs = stream.collect::<Vec<_>>().await;
    println!("vs: {:?}", vs);
}
```

Is there a way to get the `unfold()` on the producer side, the trait in the middle, and the `collect()` in the consumer side?

Things got a bit weird when I tried to use `Pin<Box<dyn Stream>>`, and in the function `get_stream`, instead of returning `Box::new(stream)`, I would return `stream.boxed()`... It does compile, but it prints an empty stream!?

This is related to a previous question about [impl stream cannot be unpinned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436221/impl-stream-cannot-be-unpinned), but that solution doesn't help my case because it won't let me pin something which is `!Unpin`.

Comment: Removed the [tag:pinning] tag, which relates to the pinning of X509 certificates (nothing to do with pinning in Rust).

Comment: The code does not compile at the line `let stream = Pin::new(stream)`. But if you remove that line, then the compiler complains that you can't call collect (no pun intended) on the stream, because the stream is `!Unpin`.

Comment: The stream returned by `unfold` can't be `Unpin` because environment captured by the closure argument could be referenced within the closure, and moving the resulting stream at an `await` point would leave those references dangling.  In this case since the closure does not actually need to be asynchronous you could use `stream::iter` together with `std::iter::from_fn`.

Comment: @eggyal, you are correct, as I tried to give a simple example, which does not justify the `Stream::unfold()` method. In my application, however, which deals with paginated searches in Elasticsearch, I do need that async environment, and that complicates things a bit.

Comment: If you know that either: (i) your closure does not hold references to captured environment across any await points; or (ii) `collect` does not move the stream... then you could workaround this with unsafe code.  But I'd probably prefer to implement my own stream type instead of using unfold.

Comment: Actually, maybe you can make use of [`poll_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/fn.poll_fn.html) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example prints an empty array because of a logic error. You initialize the streamer with `count: 4`:

```
    let streamer = Streamer { begin: 4, count: 4 };
```

But later you return `None` (i.e. "end of stream") when `count != 0`:

```
if count == 0 { // this case is never "true"
    // skipped for brevity
} else { // count != 0 -> this is always "true", so your app always returns None
    None
}
```

The fix is to invert your `if` statement. Full working source

```
use std::pin::Pin;

use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt, BoxStream};
use futures::stream::Stream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let streamer = Streamer { begin: 4, count: 4 };
    let stream = streamer.get_stream();
    let vs = stream.collect::<Vec<_>>().await;
    println!("vs: {:?}", vs);
}

pub trait GetStream {
    fn get_stream(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item=u32>>>;
}

pub struct Streamer {
    begin: u32,
    count: usize,
}

impl GetStream for Streamer {
    fn get_stream(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = u32>>> {
        let stream = stream::unfold((self.begin, self.count), |(cur, count)| async move {
            if count > 0 {
                let next_state = (cur + 1, count - 1);
                let yielded = next_state.0;
                Some((yielded, next_state))
            } else {
                None
            }
        });

        stream.boxed()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sveltin, thank you. It was right under my nose, but I wasn't looking there. Thanks again

Comment: @user3166886 Please consider "accepting" the answer if it has solved the issue